# Boost spirit grammar rule to extract just alphanumeric tokens

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-qi

I have a lexeme as below for words which are alhanumeric.

attributes = lexeme[+(boost::spirit::qi::alpha|boost::spirit::qi::digit)];

I want to have a grammar rule which skips any other characters which are not appropiate for this rule and just put these ones in a vector.

For example : input: STR1 + STR2 % STR3 () STR4 = STR5+ STR6

```
           output: (STR1, STR2, STR3, STR4, STR6)
```

I have tried below grammar but it skips everything after taking the first word in the parsing string. How can I change it to parse as I described?

```
typedef std::vector<std::wstring> Attributes;
template <typename It, typename Skipper=boost::spirit::qi::space_type>
struct AttributeParser : boost::spirit::qi::grammar<It, Attributes(),  Skipper>
{
    AttributeParser() : AttributeParser::base_type(expression)
    {
        expression = 

            *( attributes [phx::push_back(qi::_val, qi::_1)])
            >> qi::omit[*qi:char_]
            ;

        attributes = qi::lexeme[+(boost::spirit::qi::alpha|qi::boost::spirit::qi::digit)];

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(expression);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(attributes);
    }


private:
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<It, std::wstring() , Skipper> attributes;
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<It, Attributes() , Skipper> expression;

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd literally write what you describe:

```
    std::vector<std::wstring> parsed;
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(
            begin(input), end(input),
            *qi::lexeme [ +qi::alnum ],
            ~qi::alnum,
            parsed);
```

Namely:

- parse (partial) input
- parsing lexemes of alpha-numerics
- skipping anything non-alphanumeric
- put the result into the `parsed` vector

Here's the full program

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main()
{
    std::wstring input = L"STR1 + STR2 % STR3 () STR4 = STR5+ STR6";

    std::vector<std::wstring> parsed;
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(begin(input), end(input),
            *qi::lexeme [ +qi::alnum ],
            ~qi::alnum,
            parsed);

    for(auto& v : parsed)
        std::wcout << v << std::endl;
}
```

That prints

```
STR1
STR2
STR3
STR4
STR5
STR6
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are parsing the first string and pushing it into the vector:

```
*( attributes [phx::push_back(qi::_val, qi::_1)])
```

Next you are omitting anything that can be converted into a *char*:

```
>> qi::omit[*qi:char_]
```

So you are basically telling your parser to skip the rest of the string, regardless of the character being alphanumeric or not. If you want it to work you need to change

```
qi::omit[*qi::char_]
```

to something like

```
qi::omit[*(qi::char_ - qi::alnum)].
```

and that should omit any character except alphanumeric ones, which should be the start of the next string you want to keep. I can't try the code right now, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're committed to using Spirit (e.g., this is a small part of something that uses Spirit a lot otherwise), I'd do this with a custom ctype facet instead.

```
struct alpha_num: std::ctype<char> {
    alpha_num(): std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}

    static std::ctype_base::mask const* get_table() {
        // As far as we care, everything is white-space:
        static std::vector<std::ctype_base::mask> 
            rc(std::ctype<char>::table_size,std::ctype_base::space);

        // except digits and letters:
        std::fill(&rc['0'], &rc['9'], std::ctype_base::digit);
        std::fill(&rc['a'], &rc['z'], std::ctype_base::alpha);
        std::fill(&rc['A'], &rc['Z'], std::ctype_base::alpha);
        return &rc[0];
    }
};
```

From there, it's a fairly simple matter of opening the file, imbuing it with a locale using that ctype facet, and reading the tokens. Here's a quick test with your input:

```
int main() { 

    std::istringstream infile("STR1 + STR2 % STR3 () STR4 = STR5+ STR6");
    infile.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new alpha_num));

    // Initialize vector from file:
    std::vector<std::string> tokens((std::istream_iterator<std::string>(infile)),
                                     std::istream_iterator<std::string>());

    // show the tokens:
    for (auto const & s : tokens)
        std::cout << s << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
STR1
STR2
STR3
STR4
STR5
STR6
```